# AJAX CAll after page loads

Tags: ajax, servlets

I am trying to populate an html select after the page loads using an ajax call. For some reason, the servlet post isn't being called. Does anyone see what I may be doing wrong?

```
    window.onload = function(){
    var localXMLHttp = getXMLHttpRequest();
    localXMLHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
                                  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    localXMLHttp.open("POST","DateServlet",true);
    localXMLHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(localXMLHttp.readyState == 4 && localXMLHttp.status == 200) {
            alert(localXMLHttp.responseText);
            var datesToDisplay = localXMLHttp.responseText.split("*");
            var periodSelect = document.getElementById("period");
            periodSelect.options[periodSelect.options.length] = new Option(datesToDisplay[0], datesToDisplay[0]);
            periodSelect.options[periodSelect.options.length] = new Option(datesToDisplay[1], datesToDisplay[1]);
            periodSelect.options[periodSelect.options.length] = new Option(datesToDisplay[2], datesToDisplay[2]);
            periodSelect.options[periodSelect.options.length] = new Option(datesToDisplay[3], datesToDisplay[3]);
        }
    };
    localXMLHttp.send(null);
};
```

This code is posted inside of a script tag at the end of the body tag.

Comment: Install firebug and check if the request is done and what is its status...

Comment: You have provided very little information to determine the problem, so try and eliminate some primary problem-creator factors...

Comment: getXMLHttpRequest will not work on old IE which needs ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") which is why its advisable to use a JS framework for Ajax, unless you know all the cases to take into account yourself.